# show telephone number as a link in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want so show a telephone number as a "telephonelink" on my website. i show the telephone-numbers with the following php code in my template:

```
<?php if($employeeObj->getEmail() != "" && $employeeObj->getEmail() != "-"){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><?=$employeeObj->getEmail()?></td>
                            </tr>
```

how can i implement the telephone number as a link in this php code?

can anybody help me?

Comment: To where do you want to link it?

Comment: Php is server side. Html cliënt side. Links are written in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as below:

```
<?php if($employeeObj->getEmail() != "" && $employeeObj->getEmail() != "-"){ 
$phone = str_replace("/", "", $employeeObj->getEmail());
$phone = str_replace(" ", "", $phone);
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><a href="callto:<?= $phone ?>"><?= $phone ?><a/></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you... that was what iam looking for... but when i get the telephone numer with getphone() it is callto 0000/11 22 33 but i want the telephone numer in the format: +490000112233
any ideas?

Comment: From where are you getting the area code??

And to remove slash and blank space use `str_replace`

Comment: thanks... how can i impelment the `str_replace -` in the php-code from you?

Comment: Code update check `str_replace`

Comment: thx... but when i use this i get a php error.. maybe the open `{` must be close and also i want to replace tht `-` can you help me a last time?

Comment: Closed the `{` at the end. `<tr>` will not be created if condition is not matched

Mention the error as well if you get error again